# Resetar endereço do ponteiro apos ser incrementado varias vezes

Tags: c

Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define T_INT 5
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int v[T_INT],i;
    int *p = &v;


    /* Preenchendo o vetor*/
    for (i=0;i<T_INT;i++){
        v[i] = i;
    }

    /* Tentando ler com o ponteiro incrementando o endereço */
    for (i=0;i<T_INT;i++){

       printf("%d\n",(*p));
       (*p++);
       }

}
```

Eu sei que poderia utilizar [], mas estou optando utilizar assim por questões acadêmicas, como eu poderia resetar esse ponteiro para posição inicial ?

> considerando que não posso usar mais a variável 'v' pois a mesma pode
>   está fora de escopo

Comment: `int *p = &v;` devia ser `int *p = v;`. O tipo de `&v` é `(int*)[T_INT]` que não é compatível com `int*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz uma cópia do ponteiro antes de o alterar; depois reseta para essa cópia

```
    int *pbak = p;                // copia de p
    for (i = 0; i < T_INT; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        p++;
    }
    p = pbak;                     // resetando p
```

Comment: Eu vi uma outra forma em um programa, onde usava-se um -1 para dar esse reset no ponteiro

Comment: Depois de "andares 5 vezes para a frente" um `-1` nao chega. Podes meter o `-1` num ciclo (mas a cópia é mais eficiente): `for (i = 0; i < T_INT; i++) p = p - 1;`